# Como adicionar nova etapa do onepagecheckout?

Tags: php, magento

preciso criar uma nova etapa no OSC, dentro dessa etapa vai ter duas opções com radio buttons, contratar e não contratar. se sim, o total do carrinho deve ser atualizado com 1% do valor total do carrinho. já pesquisei em diversos fóruns Nacionais e internacionais, o mais perto que cheguei foi seguindo esse tutorial: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188758/how-can-i-add-a-driver-tip-in-magento-onepage-checkout-process.  Porém depois de tanto trabalho nada acontece.
Alguém sabe como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Obrigado pela dica Isvaldo Fernandes, 

Vamos lá, resumindo oque preciso fazer é o seguinte. quando o cliente chegar no OSC quero que ele escolha se quer que o  pedido dele seja entregue com ou sem o seguro. 
OBS: não posso criar um atributo e colocar opção de seguro para cada produto, o seguro em questão tem de ser para a mercadoria. quando a gente clica nas opções de frete em SEDEX por exemplo o valor do carrinho é atualizado, quero que o mesmo aconteça quando o cliente clicar em SIM - CONTRATAR - o valor que deve ser atualizado no carrinho é de 1% do valor do pedido.